# Como receber um array e imprimir seu conteúdo usando PHP?

Tags: php, array, echo

Preciso saber como faço para armazenar os dados de um array em uma variável, usando o looping abaixo:

Recebimento dos dados:

```
$sql="SELECT `devicetoken` FROM `devicetokensios`  ORDER BY `index`";

  $resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro .:" . mysql_error());

$deviceToken = array();

  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado))
{
    $deviceToken [] = $r;
}
mysql_close();
```

Depois de receber os dados, como faço para percorrer um looping e ter controle dos dados do array usando seu índice:

Exemplo de como preciso usar os dados do array:

```
for($index = 0; $index <= count($deviceToken); $index ++){

$outraVarial = $deviceToken[$index];

}
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer com "usar este mesmo array para imprimir os dados na tela"? Repare que `$deviceTokens` existe no seu código com e sem "s" no fim...

Comment: E por que você precisa passar um *array* para outro *array*? Existe algum motivo real ou você só não sabe usar o *array* original*. A técnica mais moderna para varrer um *array* já existente é o [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Aí dentro dele você faz o que quiser com cada elemento.

Comment: Você gostaria de mostrar cada posição do array ou quer imprimir o array tudo de uma vez?

Comment: Quero so retornoar o conteúdo do array :D

Comment: Você quer retornar ou imprimir o `$deviceTokens`? Como você precisa desses dados do array? Qual a finalizadade deles?

Comment: Preciso deles em formato string. Ele vai retornar os devices tokens para envio de push na APNS. Mas agora estou usando a função implode() e estou recebendo um erro dizendo : `Warning: implode(): Argument must be an array in`

Comment: Achei o erro, eu tava usando o sinal de <= no looping, então ele acessava um valor acima do que tinha no array. Mas ainda estou me preocupando com o tipo... vou fazer umas verificações.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desconsiderando o erro de sintaxe apontado pelo Sergio e considerando o requerimento de o array ser impresso como uma string, você tem, sem iterar, pelo menos três opções mas todas seguidas de um echo ou print:

1. [implode()](http://www.php.net/implode)

   ```
   <?php echo implode( '', $deviceTokens );
   ```

O problema de implode() é que ele não trabalha com array associativos então, se o array tiver índices em string, eles serão ignorados e a saída não será o esperado.

2. [serialize()](http://www.php.net/serialize)

   ```
   <?php echo serialize( $devideTokens );
   ```

O problema de serialize é a rigidez das informações resultantes. Uma vez serializado um array você não consegue fazer nada de útil sem des-serializá-lo. Por isso é um formato mais adequado para armazenamento de dados que não requeiram normalização.

3. [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/json_encode)

   ```
   <?php echo json_encode( $deviceTokens );
   ```

A mais flexível das opções pois por ser universal pode ser maniipulado até por outras linguagens.

E tem a opção de iterar, se tudo o mais falhar:

```
$output = NULL;

foreach( $deviceTokens as $key => $value ) {

    // É óbvio que você não vai fazer assim :p

    $output . 'Chave: ' . $key . "\nValor: " . $value;
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: eu precisaria de um controle por indice numério. Para controlar ele com um for();

Por exemplo:



`// Como preciso

for ($index = 0; $index<= count($array);$index++){
 

 $valorRecebido = $array[$index];

}`

Comment: Isso já é outra pergunta. Você queria saber como mostrar esse array. Apesar de estranho por ser uma pergunta bem mais simples do que mexer com banco de dados, eu respondi. Caso ainda seja a mesma dúvida, edite a questão e forneça mais detalhes. Eu edito a minha tanto quanto possível para responder.

Answer (score 0):

Pronto, consegui oque queria!

Obrigado.

Abaixo o código:

```
$meuArray = array();

$meuArray []= "A";
$meuArray []= "k";
$meuArray []= "Blan";


for($lop = 0; $lop < count($meuArray);$lop++){

echo ($meuArray[$lop]);


}
```

Comment: Você sabe que, considerando essa estrutura, um simples `echo implode( '', $meuArray )` já resolveria seu problema, né?

Comment: Sim resolveu mas não solucionei tudo. Vou explicar, estou tentando enviar um devicetoken para um servidor de push notification, porém, preciso fazer isso para centenas de devices, então para automatizar, eu estou tentando criar um sistema pequeno em PHP para isso.

 Já consigo disparar manualmente um push. E já consigo executar o sistema que estou fazendo, porém com o sistema os push's não chegam. 
 Na tela vem a mensagem de sucesso, mas na prática nada acontece.

Comment: Eu estou usando o `$minhaString = implode($meuArray);`.

Comment: vou iniciar outra pergunta mais focada aos novos problemas que estão surgindo. Mas Obrigado!!!

Comment: Se o array verdadeiro e o array acima forem ambos indexados (numéricos) e unidimensionais o problema é em outro lugar. Acho que vale um `var_dump()` sobre o array verdadeiro pra investigar. De repente tem uma dimensão a mais que pode estar acabando com o o implode(). Mas ainda que seja assim, ainda mais que me parece estar havendo interação com outra linguagem (JS né?), JSON é ainda mais indicado.

Comment: o JSON surge no meio do projeto, mas não interage com este array. Vou iniciar outra pergunta e vou mostar o código na integra e explicar bem o cenário.

 Vou adicionar o link aqui para que vocês possam acompanhar.

Comment: Galera, está aqui a pergunta nova com o codigo completo:

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40583/como-construir-um-simples-server-apns-com-php