# Como construir um simples server APNS com PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, array, apple-push-notification

Estou criando um pequeno serviço de disparo de notificações.

Fiz este codigo, para fazer vários disparos de pushs, onde os devicetokens vem de um servidor. 
 Porém estou encontrando os seguinte problema:

Quando atribuo diretamente um token no array `$deviceToken`, o push chega normalmente ao smartphone.

Quando o token vem do servidor, aparece a mensagem de sucesso do envio, porém o push não chega ao smartphone.

Código:

```
<?php

include "conexao.php";

$sql="SELECT `devicetoken` FROM `devicetokensios`  ORDER BY `index`";

$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro .:" . mysql_error());

$deviceToken = array();


// Passando tokens para o array
  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado))
{
     $deviceToken [] = $r['devicetoken'];


}

// Coloque sua senha do certificado aqui:
$passphrase = '';

// Coloque sua mensagem aqui:
$message = 'Teste de novas mensagens!!!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'dev30.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Abre uma conexão com o servidor APNS
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Falha para conectar: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Conectado a APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Cria o corpo do payload
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Codifica o payload como JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Looping Principal de Envio
for($idx = 0; $idx< count($deviceToken);$idx++){

// Construindo o binário da notificação
$msg = chr(0).pack('n', 32).pack('H*',$deviceToken[$idx]).pack('n', strlen($payload)).$payload;


// Enviando para o servidor
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Mensagem não enviada' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Mensagem enviada com sucesso.  ||  ' . PHP_EOL;

// tempo para intervalo entre mensagens
usleep(1000000); 
}

// Fecha conexão com os servidores
mysql_close();
fclose($fp);

?>
```

No servidor a coluna `devicetoken` está com as seguintes definições:

> char(64), utf8_general_ci

Uma observação importante, quando coloco manualmente vários devices (no caso o mesmo varias vezes) no array, consigo fazer o looping tbm de envio, enviando varias vezes. Mas a intenção é que sejam para vários diferentes.

Comment: Eu estava observando isso agora.

Comment: Eu não sou "expert" em PHP, meu forte é outra linguagem. Mas estou precisando ter um server em PHP para testes. Então estou começando agora, de maneira mais profunda, em PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notei que estava ocorrendo perda dos últimos dígitos dos devicetokens no servidor devido ao comprimento da string, então ajustei a coluna para um novo comprimento de dados e inseri novamente o device token no servidor.
 Após testes usando o banco de dados como fonte dos tokens pude constatar que estava resolvido.

Consegui resolver o problema ajustando o servidor para as seguintes definições:

> varchar(64), utf8_bin